# Mocha test not running the `try..finally` clause

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I am running my Node.js tests with Mocha. When I add a `try..finally` clause I expect that Mocha will run the `finally` bit after the test. It works with errors and exceptions, but not when the test times out.

The tests below show the issue in detail.

```
describe('try-finally', () => {
  it('should run finally with an error', async() => {
    console.log('starting')
    try {
      console.log('started')
      throw new Error('Error!')
      console.log('finished')
    } finally { 
      console.log('finally!')
    } 
  }); 
  it('should run finally with a timeout', async() => {
    console.log('starting')
    try {
      console.log('started')
      await timeout()
      console.log('finished')
    } finally {
      console.log('finally!')
    }
  });
});

function timeout() {
  return new Promise(ok => {
    setTimeout(ok, 10*1000)
  })
}
```

To run the test: save into a file `try-finally.js`, install Mocha with `npm install -g mocha` and then run test with `mocha --exit try-finally.js`. Output:

```
$ mocha --exit try-finally.js

  try-finally
starting
started
finally!
    1) should run finally with an error
starting
started
    2) should run finally with a timeout


  0 passing (2s)
  2 failing

  1) try-finally
       should run finally with an error:
     Error: Error!
      at Context.it (try-finally.js:9:13)

  2) try-finally
       should run finally with a timeout:
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. /home/alex/devo/batrasio/try-finally.js)
```

Both tests fail; the first one runs the `finally` clause and displays "finally!", while the second times out (waits for 10s when the test default timeout is 2s) and does not run the `finally` clause.

A couple of searches on Google and here on Stack Overflow yielded nothing. What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible, or do I need to use the obnoxious `beforeEach()` and `afterEach()` functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `finally` block will run after the contents of the `try` block, not necessarily the whole test. Things like errors and exceptions are meant to be caught in the `try` block but with a timeout, the error is thrown by `mocha` (so outside of your `try` block).

If you need to run the `finally` block after the test is finished and it is taking too long, you can change the default timeout by putting

`this.timeout(<insert time in ms>);`

inside of your `it` function (or the `describe` function if you want it to apply to everything).

If you are wanting to do the same thing after every test, then yes the `afterEach()` function is the way to go.

Comment: Trouble is, the task in `finally` is cleanup, and it differs for every test. The `afterEach()` function is necessarily the same, so I would need to ungroup everything. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Right, that's why I'm saying the `afterEach` should only be used if you need the same behavior for all tests. Do you need the timeout to go indefinitely, like does extending the default timeout not work? Another option would be to include each test in it's own `describe` block and then you can tailor the `afterEach` to every individual test

Comment: Sometimes tests fail because they don't complete. Having an infinite timeout would not be ideal :'( Thanks!